# Prevent simultaneous actions from two devices to same collection

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firestore and Flutter (Dart). This question is  more conceptual than anything.

Database structure is `Users` collection containing `A` through `G` collection (owned by user).

At the same level as the A through G collection is (int) `lastUpdated` field. When a device inserts, updates, or deletes within their slice of the Firestore, a timestamp is generated by the device and stored in `lastUpdated` both on the Firestore and device. If user opens a different device with an older timestamp, it gets compared to server to determine that it needs to pull data down rather than push its data up.

As long as all server calls are completed before a different device tries to make a change, everything works great.

But, if someone makes an action on two devices at the same time (or before previous device's actions are complete), the algorithms cross and it either ends in all of the data being deleted or duplicate records.

I thought about adding a (bool) `syncInProgress` field to the Firestore that becomes `true` on connect and `false` after finishing, but if someone's device disconnects during the process, it might get stuck in `true` and effectively prevent all future interactions with the DB (without admin intervention).

My other thought was that if a device gets notified that `syncInProgress` is true (and therefore  they need to wait to sync), they might also be presented a button to override, which would manually set `syncInProgress` back to false.

This all sounds way too complex, and usually when that happens I'm overthinking something and there is a better way. Suggestions?

Comment: That you tried to use Firestore Transactions?

Comment: Wow just looked that up and initial reading is very promising!

Comment: So I've been reading about this throughout the day. It looks like a single transaction can only apply to a single document? My structure is Collection (Users) -> Documents (User) -> Subcollections (A through G) -> Documents (actual data). The transaction I'm trying to accomplish modifies sub collections A through G and all documents within. Can I somehow run A through G as separate transactions and modify all documents (actual data) within a single transaction?

Comment: It appears that I need transaction.getAll, which only exists in nodejs unfortunately! This seems so promising.